# Unable to import Hibernate project into workspace

Tags: hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I am new to using IntelliJ Idea. I downloaded the example code from the site - [Java Persistence With Hibernate](http://jpwh.org/examples/jpwh2/jpwh-2e-examples-20151103.zip) and opened the project in IntelliJ Idea IDE. The IDE is showing all compilation errors even though I am able to build the project from my command line terminal using `mvn clean install` command. I am not sure where I am going wrong and I do not see any errors configuring the project. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you tell IntellIJ to import the project as a maven project?

Comment: @Naros I did File > Open and pointed it to the hibernate project. It automatically detected all the pom and configured. Since then, all the Java files are showing compile time errors stating hibernate related classes are not getting detected.

Comment: when you open pom.xml files, is there any dependency error? Did you try 'maven projects > reimport All maven projects'?